# Using the same FormGroup component twice in within parent form - reactive forms, angular

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, reactive, reusability, formbuilder

I was wondering if it's possible to use the same FormGroup component twice within a parent form? And how do I make it unique so I can use the same form controls?

Comment: Yes, you need to wrap your component as custom form and then you can reuse it in multiple places. Look for ControlValueAccessor interface